# OpenLayers Problem with adding custom wms address

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have a problem with specific wms address. I would like to add another one wms server with specific layer to my project.

```
const wmsSource1 = new TileWMS({
    url: "http://geoportal.powiatboleslawiecki.pl:80/ggp?",
    params: {
    LAYERS: "kontury",
    },
    serverType: "geoserver",
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
})
```

coordinates of the center of view [EPSG:3857]

```
 [1731811, 6665020]
```

The address works fine in other applications such qgis. I've checked layers name, address and everything looks ok. I do not know why I can not see it...

In qgis description of this wms you can see:

```
GetCapabilitiesUrl  http://geoportal.powiatboleslawiecki.pl/ggp?
```

```
GetMapUrl   http://geoportal.powiatboleslawiecki.pl:80/ggp?SERVICE=WMS&
```

```
GetFeatureInfoUrl   http://geoportal.powiatboleslawiecki.pl:80/ggp?SERVICE=WMS&
```

```
GetLegendGraphic    http://geoportal.powiatboleslawiecki.pl:80/ggp?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&width=20&height=20&layer=kontury&
```

thanks in advance,

Piotr

Comment: The source does not allow cross origin access.  Remove `crossOrigin: "anonymous",` and it will work, but you will have tainted canvas.

Comment: Thank you Mike, but the crossOrigin is not an issue...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-tiled-forked-plq239?file=/main.js

Comment: thnak you Mike for you time, yes it solved problem. From now I use firefox with extension to allow crosOrigin. For me, when I use localhost it works.